# How can I check condition inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am using dynamic select using formArray. I want to disable an option in the select field if option is already selected.

I am using angular 8

```
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm">

    <div formArrayName="question1">
        <label>Question 1</label>
        <div *ngFor="let que of question.controls;let i=index">
            <select  [formControlName]="i">
                <option *ngFor="let emp of employeeList" [value]="emp.id">{{ emp.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <button (click)="delPerson(i)">Delete</button>
        </div>    
        <button (click)="addPerson()">Add Person</button> 
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!surveyForm.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Already selected in a different question is what you mean?

Comment: Hi @unni bhaskar if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the form Control stored inside `formArray` to check for the `id` and `selected` value

```
    <div formArrayName="question1" *ngFor="let que of surveyForm.get('question1').controls;let i=index">
        <label>Question 1</label>
        <div>
            <select  [formControlName]="i">
                <option *ngFor="let emp of employeeList" [value]="emp.id" [disabled]='emp.id == que.value'>{{ emp.name }}</option>
            </select>
            Selected Id : {{que.value}}
            <button (click)="delPerson(i)">Delete</button>
        </div>    
        <button (click)="addPerson()">Add Person</button> 
    </div>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!surveyForm.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Refer Stackblitz Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svor7x

Answer (score 0):

you can use a template variable for the select element and check if the element value is equal to the option value

```
<ng-container>
        <div *ngFor="let que of question.controls;let i=index">

            <select  [formControlName]="i" #selectElem>
                <option *ngFor="let emp of employeeList" [value]="emp.id"
                        [disabled]="selectElm.value == emp.id">
                 {{ emp.name }}
                </option>

            </select>
            <button (click)="delPerson(i)">Delete</button>
        </div>    
</ng-container>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skndrc)